# set div equally in the parent div along with text

Tags: html, css

I want divs to be set equally in the parent div along with text.

Just shown in the image.

[image: here is the image]

```css
#container {
  text-align: justify;
}
#container > div {
  width: 90px; /* Declare your value. Can be in relative units. */
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: #f2f1f1;

  /* IE fix. */
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  height: 90px;
}
#container:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>
                                    <div></div>

                                </div>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#container .box-container {
  width: 90px; /* Declare your value. Can be in relative units. */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#container .box-container .img {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="img"></div>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>

</div>
```